# Limit of get data from mongodb

Tags: mongodb

[image]
[image]

Background:

I want to fetch more data from my mongodb, I've inserted some images[400 thousands with 224*224 in JPEG format] via ExportByteArray.

When I get the data from Mongodb, I can only fetch 7000 documents.

If I want to get more, like 20000, The AbsoluteTiming is 0.03s, and returned nothing. so it's not the problem like timeout problem.

When I'm looking at in terminal, I didn't see the increasing of memory usage.

Is it just the out of memory problem?

How can I get more debug information from Mathematica?

Or are there some default setting's limit of MongoDB？

I've tested that 4000 images with 224*224 size need low memory.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find the reason why this happened? I'm looking for storing 30K documents in MongoDB. Thx!